# Incircle of ∆DFE touches C, incircle of ∆DFC touches G, I$_2$ is incircle center of ∆FCE. Prove ∠I$_2$GC=90°

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, triangles

[image]

> In the figure, $C$ is the point of contact of incircle of $\triangle DEF $ and $DE$. $I_1$ is the incentre of $\triangle DCF$ and $I_1G \perp FC$. $I_2$ is the incentre of $\triangle CEF$. Prove that $I_2G \perp CF$.

$I_1G \perp FC \implies I_1G$ is the inradius of incircle of $\triangle DCF$. I tried to do 'angle chasing' but I am not able to use line $CF$. I think finding $\angle FCE$ in terms of vertex angles of $\triangle DEF$ would work, but I am not able to figure out any such relation. Please help!

Answer (score 1):

Since $I_1$ is the incenter, we have

$$2CG = FC + DC - FD\tag{1}$$

Also, given $C$ is the contact point of incircle $\triangle DEF$, we have

$$FD - FE = DC - EC\tag{2}$$

Plug (2) into (1), we get

$$2CG = FC + EC - FE\tag{3}$$

which means, just as for the incircle with center $I_1$, $G$ is also the tangential point for the incircle of center $I_2$. (Assume the tangential point $X$, $CX=CG$ from (3). Hence, $G$ and $X$ are the same point.)

Thus,

$$I_2G \perp CF$$